# Bean validation size of a List?

Tags: java, bean-validation

How can I set a bean validation constraint that a `List` should at minimum contain 1 and at maximum contain 10 elements?

None of the following works:

```
@Min(1)
@Max(10)
@Size(min=1, max=10)
private List<String> list;
```

Comment: For me, @Size works perfectly. Can you show us code where you validating it? Did you use import javax.validation.constraints.Size?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I created simple class:

```
public class Mock {

    @Size(min=1, max=3)
    private List<String> strings;

    public List<String> getStrings() {
        return strings;
    }

    public void set(List<String> strings) {
        this.strings = strings;
    }

}
```

And test:

```
Mock mock = new Mock();
mock.setStrings(Collections.emptyList());
final Set<ConstraintViolation<Mock>> violations1 = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator().validate(mock);
assertFalse(violations1.isEmpty());

mock.setStrings(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D"));
final Set<ConstraintViolation<Mock>> violations2 = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator().validate(mock);
assertFalse(violations2.isEmpty());
```

It seems that `@Size` annotation is working well. It comes from `javax.validation.constraints.Size`

Comment: Got it: I'm using `spring-mvc`, and the validation is only applied on the `List` if the list is defined at all in the input parameters (I just left out the list in my request, because I set min=1). Solution is to use `@NotNull` `@Size` in conjunction if the list should always exist and have at least a single item.

Comment: @SledgeHammer can you open another question and put some code that is not working to check it?

Answer (score 13):

You can use @NotEmpty to check for empty list. This make sure there is at least one item in list.

Comment: `@NotEmpty` can only be applied to pain `String`.

Comment: From Hibernate validator doc: @NotEmpty Supported data types
CharSequence, Collection, Map and arrays

Comment: As Hibernate @NotEmpty annotation is deprecated, you should now use `javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty`